# php call function name from array

Tags: php, arrays, function

hi i want get function name from array
how to do that

```
public function cuturls($url){
    $long_url = urlencode($url);
    $api_token = 'xxx';
    $api_url = "https://cut-urls.com/api?api={$api_token}&url={$long_url}";
    $result = @json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url),TRUE);
    if($result["shortenedUrl"]) {
        return $result["shortenedUrl"];
    } else {
        return $this->ouo($url);
    }
}
```

want to convert this function

```
public function docut($url){
    global $filesize77;
    global $cutpost;
    if(empty($cutpost) or $cutpost==='cutearn'){
        if($filesize77 <= '1073741824'){
            return array($this->cuturls($url),'cuturls');
        }else if($filesize77 > '1073741824' and $filesize77 <= '2147483648'){
            return array($this->cuturls($this->adlinkme($url)),'cuturls');
        }else if($filesize77 > '2147483648' and $filesize77 <= '3221225472'){
            return array($this->cuturls($this->adlinkme($this->cutearn($url))),'cuturls');
        }
    }
```

want to convert for this type by using array have functions names
how to callback

```
public function docut($url){
    global $filesize77;
    global $cutpost;
    $cutarray = array('cuturls', 'adlinkme', 'cutearn', 'cutwin');
    if(empty($cutpost) or $cutpost===$cutarray[3]){
        if($filesize77 <= '1073741824'){
            return array($this->$cutarray[0]($url),$cutarray[0]);
        }else if($filesize77 > '1073741824' and $filesize77 <= '2147483648'){
            return array($this->$cutarray[0]($this->$cutarray[1]($url)),$cutarray[0]);
        }else if($filesize77 > '2147483648' and $filesize77 <= '3221225472'){
            return array($this->$cutarray[0]($this->$cutarray[1]($this->$cutarray[2]($url))),$cutarray[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand what you're asking for here.  Can you add more text explaining what you are trying to do and which functions or arrays you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

```
call_user_func_array($func,$parameters);
```

`$func` is function name as string , `$parameters` is parameteres to `$func` as array.
read the doc :-
http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

usage:-

```
<?php
function abc($str){
    print $str;
}
call_user_func_array("abc",array('Working'));
?>
```

When it put in your question:-

```
public function docut($url){
    global $filesize77;
    global $cutpost;
    $cutarray = array('cuturls', 'adlinkme', 'cutearn', 'cutwin');
    if(empty($cutpost) or $cutpost===$cutarray[3]){
        if($filesize77 <= '1073741824'){
            return array(call_user_func_array(array($this,$cutarray[0]),$url),$cutarray[0]);
        }else if($filesize77 > '1073741824' and $filesize77 <= '2147483648'){
            return array( call_user_func_array(array($this,$cutarray[0]),call_user_func_array(array($this,$cutarray[0]),$url)),$cutarray[0]);
        }else if($filesize77 > '2147483648' and $filesize77 <= '3221225472'){
            return array(call_user_func_array(array($this,$cutarray[0]),call_user_func_array(array($this,$cutarray[1]),call_user_func_array(array($this,$cutarray[2]),$url))),$cutarray[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: function 'cuturls' not found or invalid function name ?

Comment: the function name who in array not paramater

Comment: and the two function cuturls and docut in same class

Comment: @MohamedShosha now you can replace docut.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `{..}(..)` syntax. I.e `$this->{$cutarray[0]}(...)`

```
public function docut($url){
    global $filesize77;
    global $cutpost;
    $cutarray = ['cuturls', 'adlinkme', 'cutearn', 'cutwin'];
    if(empty($cutpost) or $cutpost===$cutarray[3]){
        if($filesize77 <= '1073741824') {
            return [$this->{$cutarray[0]}($url), $cutarray[0]];
        } else if($filesize77 > '1073741824' and $filesize77 <= '2147483648'){
            return [$this->{$cutarray[0]}($this->$cutarray[1]($url)), $cutarray[0]];
        } else if($filesize77 > '2147483648' and $filesize77 <= '3221225472') {
            return [$this->{$cutarray[0]}($this->{$cutarray[1]}($this->{$cutarray[2]}($url))), $cutarray[0]];
        }
    }
```

If you add more cases to this function, you should really think about wrapping this inside an loop or something else. Currently your code is very hard to read and understand...

```
public function docut($url){
    global $filesize77;
    global $cutpost;
    $cutarray = ['cuturls', 'adlinkme', 'cutearn', 'cutwin'];
    if(empty($cutpost) or $cutpost === $cutarray[3]) {
        switch {
        case: $filesize77 > 0x80000000 && $filesize77 <= 0xC0000000:
            $url = $this->{$cutarray[2]}($url);
        case: $filesize77 > 0x40000000 && $filesize77 <= 0x80000000:
            $url = $this->{$cutarray[1]}($url);
        case $filesize77 < 0x40000000;
            $url = $this->{$cutarray[0]}($url);
        }

        return [$url, $cutarray[0]];
    }
}
```